# How do I mitigate replay attacks when talking about actions that shouldn't happen twice?

Tags: ajax, nonce

A nonce is supposed to first help me against CSRF and help against replay attacks is just a bonus if I "personalize" the nonce to something like `pay-user-{id}`, but here's the problem - if my link looked like `/wordpress/admin_ajax.php?action=pay-user&id=20&security=ej3548` I have 2 cases to take care of:

1. I created a nonce without the specific user ID, `pay-user` - if an attacker obtains the nonce, he can make me click that link and **pay any user.**
2. I created a nonce with the specific user ID, `pay-user-{id}` - if an attacker obtains the nonce, **he can only make me replay that request, since the nonce was made to verify that specific (to `{id}`) action.**

But that's still an issue in a lot of cases, paying someone is a prime example. I can't be made to pay someone else, but if I make that request 10 times, I'll pay that specific person 10 times.

Is there no specific "per request" hashing?

What to do?

Comment: How do you track and validate the payments? Do they have some sort of ID? Or status e.g. pending and paid?

Comment: @AnttiKoskinen That's a validation issue - a good question, sure, but it's out of the scope of the question which is about "why do nonces have an expiration timer and aren't, well, nonces?"

Comment: Ah, now I get it as you put it that way. You'll need to dig into the WP release notes (around 2.0.3) to find the reasoning for that as the codex (https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces) only notes that they aren't real nonce by design. Some reasoning can be found https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/77225/nonces-can-be-reused-multiple-times-bug-security-issue and https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/223816/how-to-expire-a-nonce, though.